# How to update view frequently?

Tags: ios, swift

This is what I try to do in code:

```
for i in 1...1000000000 {
    print(i)
    self.title = "\(i)"
}
```

on console it prints everything, but I can't see any updates in my navigation bar. Why?

Comment: have you tried to update the title after the loop? Is it updated?

Comment: Because your display will be refreshed _after_ your loop. You could have a look at the [`CADisplayLink`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cadisplaylink?changes=_8) instead

Comment: Do you have any example for that?;) Thank you...

Comment: [Here you go](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/swift-3-so-i-wanted-to-animate-a-label-14dd2b332ef9)

Comment: @Alladinian you are the best;) If you answer I will accept and upvote it. Thank you again.

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk done. Glad that helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually you could have a look at [`CADisplayLink`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cadisplaylink?changes=_8) which basically is a timer that is synchronized with the refresh of the display. At its most basic form it would be something like this:

```
func createDisplayLink() {
    let displaylink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(step))
    displaylink.add(to: .current, forMode: .defaultRunLoopMode)
}

@objc func step(displaylink: CADisplayLink) {
    // Do the updates
}
```

**Note**: Please note that `step` will be called *a lot*, essentially on each screen update, which is 60-120 fps on current devices.

Comment: Show me please when should I call `step` function and when should I create a `CADisplayLink`? Would you inject it into my example? Thank you very much...

Comment: Well, the idea is that you do not call the `step` function, the displaylink does. Once you add it to a thread (`current` in the example assumes that you're on the `main` thread - you can explicitly use `.main` as well) the `step` will be called on _each_ display update giving you the opportunity to refresh any views. I'm not sure on what you're after in your example, since it's just a loop basically... would it be possible to expand your example to a more concrete one?